# Flash Error #1010

Tags: flash

when i run my flash file (test it) in the output panel i get the following error

TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.

i read some where, that this was caused because one of the variables is set to null. after looking at my code i found out that the following line was causing this output

```
arrSelectedIndex[i] = -1;
```

this is later on used as the selected index in a group of radio buttons.

my question is, would having the selected index set to -1 be an issue ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like `arrSelectedIndex` is null on this line.  Trace back to where it is supposed to be assigned.  Use the debugger if trace statements aren't enough to figure out what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The RadioButtonGroup takes a `selectedValue` property, not a `selectedIndex`. So you can't set the selectedIndex of an RBG to anything at all, not just not -1.

You can retrieve the value of a radioButton in a RadioButtonGroup by using the method `RadioButtonGroup.getRadioButtonAt(index:int)`.