# TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties?

Tags: actionscript-3

**Error:**

> TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties. at Untitled_2_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()[Untitled_2_fla.MainTimeline::frame1:4]

Can't seem to figure out what's that about.

**Here's my code:**

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
btnMc1.txtSourceMc.gotoAndStop();
btnMc1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, over);
btnMc1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, out);
function over(e: MouseEvent) {
    btnMc1.buttonMode = true;
    btnMc1.gotoAndPlay(1);
}
function out(e: MouseEvent) { 
    btnMc1.gotoAndPlay(62);
}
```

Comment: can you try `this.buttonMode = true;` instead of `btnMc1.buttonMode = true;` ?

Comment: Something doesn't exist. Either `btnMc1` or `txtSourceMc`. You tell `txtSourceMc` to stop. Is that your intention? Or rather `btnMc1.gotoAndStop()`?

Comment: also `this.gotoAndPlay` instead of `btnMc1.gotoAndPlay`

Comment: If the code you've shown is indeed the code that's throwing the error, then it means that at the time this frame runs, there is no instance with the name of `btnMc1` or the timeline of `btnMc1` doesn't have an instance named `txtSouceMc` (at the time this code runs).  Double check that you have the correctly spelled instance names set.    Most likely, `txtSourceMc` doesn't exist on the first frame of `btnMc1`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flash Error #1010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2542493/flash-error-1010)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the variable btnMc1, such as var btnMc1 And you're going to have to give it a class such as var btnMc1:

```
whatEverObjectICreated = new whatEverObjectICreated;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
btnMc1.txtSourceMc.gotoAndStop();
```

Change that to

```
btnMc1.txtSourceMc.gotoAndStop(1);
```

Make sure that you've named you MCs correctly. Firstly, go to your stage, and click on **btnMc1**. Make sure you've name it as such in the properties panel(windows -> properties). Next, double click onto btnMc1 and do the same for **txtSourceMc**, make sure that it has the correct name. Im assuming that you have txtSourceMc inside btnMc1 on the timeline.

If the problem persists, it is probably because whatever you're loading into btnMc1 or txtSourceMc is too huge. So it cannot instantiate on the frame you're trying to call it in this code, thus it returns as undefined.

To solve this, right click onto btnMc1 from the library and select properties. Then select export for actionscript and make sure that the box for exporting on frame1 is checked. Do the same for txtSourceMc.